# API Uri is not mapped to Controller

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have created new controller `UsersController.cs` and trying to get access to it from `FetchData.razor.cs`, however there is no connection. I have figured this out by setting breakpoint at:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> applicationUsers = await _userManager.Users
            .Include(u => u.UserRoles)
                .ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role).ToListAsync();
```

and it is not getting called. Why so and how to fix that?
Something wrong in this one, but I don't understand exactly what `api/fetchdata`?

```
  this.applicationUserList = await this.httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<ApplicationUserDTO>>("api/fetchdata");
```

**UsersController.cs:**

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  [ApiController]
  public class UsersController : ControllerBase
  {

    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;
    private List<ApplicationUserDTO> applicationUsersDTO = new List<ApplicationUserDTO>();

    public UsersController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IMapper mapper)
    {
      this._context = context;
      this._userManager = userManager;
      this._mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
      System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ApplicationUser> applicationUsers = await _userManager.Users
            .Include(u => u.UserRoles)
                .ThenInclude(ur => ur.Role).ToListAsync();

      this.applicationUsersDTO = applicationUsers
                  .Select(person => new ApplicationUserDTO
                  {
                    Id = person.Id,
                    FirstName = person.FirstName,
                    Email = person.Email
                  }).ToList();

      //ApplicationUserDTO applicationUsersDTO = _mapper.Map<ApplicationUserDTO>(applicationUsers);
      return Ok(applicationUsersDTO);
    }
  }
```

**FetchData.razor.cs:**

```
 public partial class FetchData
  {
    [Inject]
    public HttpClient httpClient { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ApplicationUserDTO> applicationUserList { get; set; }
    protected bool isLoaded = false;

    public FetchData()
    {

    }

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
      this.applicationUserList = await this.httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<ApplicationUserDTO>>("api/fetchdata");
      this.isLoaded = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You should use the route specified by the route attribute on the controller: `[Route("api/[controller]")]` means `/api/Users` because your controller is named UsersController. So in this case, you need to replace `/api/fetchdata` with `/api/Users` in the `GetFromJsonAsync` call.

Comment: [Route("api/[controller]")] specifies the route as "api/Users" .
Because you used [controller] it takes the name of the Controller less "Controller" hence "Users".

Comment: Solution is what you all has already mentioned. However after fixing api path I was getting the same the problem still. There was an issue with authorization as well. So I have deleted DB, applied new migrations, updated DB, then created a new user ang logged in again. Now everything seems to be working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `this.applicationUserList = await this.httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<IEnumerable<ApplicationUserDTO>>("api/fetchdata");`

Do you have a controller named `fetchdata` ? ==> "api/fetchdata"

I guess you meant "api/users", right ?

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?